# Rails: migrating production database, need to create new data for every existing user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, database-migration

I have a production db in my Ruby on Rails application, with users and stuff. Now when implementing a new feature I need to create some new data for every existing user. Is there some clever way to do it? Rake script maybe?

More details:

I have a User table. Now I added Bookmarks table. The idea is that every user has 5 bookmarks with prefilled data by default. Easy to do for new users, but how about existing ones? Creating the data on user login is one option, but it feels kinda dirty.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to use `rails runner` for one off scripts like this which allows you to easily run scripts with the rails env loaded.  .

I suggest using [activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) to speed it up if you have lots of users.

We could make a script called make_bookmarks.rb in the scripts directory like this:

```
require 'activerecord-import'

bookmarks = []
User.all.each do |user|
    ["value1","value2","value3","value4","value5"].each do |value|
        bookmarks << user.bookmarks.new(:col => value)
    end
end

# import the bookmarks all with bulk sql = much faster
Bookmark.import bookmarks
```

then to run it `rails runner scripts/make_bookmarks.rb`

Answer (score 1):

One was to include the data transition in your migration like (under the assumption your has_many relationship uses a join model user_bookmark.rb):

```
class AddBookmarksTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :bookmarks, :force => true do |t|
      t.string  :some_col
      t.timestamps
    end
    create_table :user_bookmarks, :force => true do |t|
      t.integer  :bookmark_id, user_id
      t.timestamps
    end
    # create the 5 bookmarks you want to seed as values for existing users
    Bookmark.create(:some_col => 'value')
    Bookmark.create(:some_col => 'value')
    Bookmark.create(:some_col => 'value')
    Bookmark.create(:some_col => 'value')
    Bookmark.create(:some_col => 'value')
    # add values to the join table for your model
    User.all.each{|u| Bookmark.all.each{|b| UserBookmark.create(:user_id => u.id, :bookmark_id => b.id)}}
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :bookmarks
  end
end
```

In your user.rb you should have

```
has_many :bookmarks
```

and bookmark.rb

```
belongs_to :user
```

The other way (preferred) would be to just use your migration to create your tables, because seed data doesn't really belong in a migration, and to have a custom rake task that does the work for you inside lib/tasks.

lib/tasks/add_bookmarks_to_existing_users.rake

```
namespace :db do
  desc "Add bookmarks to existing users"
  task :add_bookmarks_to_existing_users => :environment do
    # create seed book marks (under impression none exist right now and associations have been set up in user and bookmark models)
    Bookmark.create(:some_col => 'value')
    Bookmark.create(:some_col => 'value')
    Bookmark.create(:some_col => 'value')
    Bookmark.create(:some_col => 'value')
    Bookmark.create(:some_col => 'value')
    User.all.each{|u| u.bookmarks << Bookmark.all}
  end
end
```

After that you can just run:

```
rake db:add_bookmarks_to_existing_users
```

Comment: Funny thing, tried that rake task. It works, but it creates db entries only for the last user.